# Is there a way to burn a python program to a disc?

Tags: python, windows, burn

I made this cool geometry, and algebra problem solver, and I wanted to burn it to a c for my friends, so they can run it almost like they would if it was a game?  Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Would it be acceptable to put the Python installer and your script on the CD, so your friends first install Python, then double-click your script? If so, that's the easiest solution for you. If not, see Ashwini Chaudhary's answer, which is easier on your friends, at the expense of taking a little more work on your part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way could be to convert your program to `.exe` and then burn it. There are many libraries available to convert a python program to an `.exe`,like:

- [cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/)
- [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/)

Comment: Note that ``cx_freeze`` also works for Linux and OS X, making it a very powerful tool.

Comment: @Lattyware Does it works for both `debian` and `rpm` based Linux OS? I mean the executable created by it.

Comment: Yeah, it produces a statically linked executable rather than a package, so the only thing is architecture. It's a little unusual for Linux (and means you'll have a really large file to send around), but it'll get the job done. Naturally it's always better to recommend Linux users to use the package manager first.

Answer (score 1):

Well, python is an interpreted language, it needs an "interpreter" (the `python` program) to read the .py file and run it. Helpfully, there are many programs (like [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org)) that can bundle up the python interpreter and your python files into one single .exe package. (For you to put on a cd and share with anyone you want!)

Answer (score 0):

As a practical matter, py2exe is probably the way to go for most normal use cases.

But if you want to distribute your application as pure python, you can do so by including a [portable distribution](http://www.portablepython.com/) of python (and all necessary libaries) along with your application.