# Can I write python onto a disk

Tags: python, exe, final, production

So, I have a game that I made with Ursina, and I have packaged it up into a standalone exe file, with pyinstaller, and that all works. My question is, is there a way that I can write this onto a disk(by disk I mean like a CD/xbox game disk, not a part of the computer), that I can run on another computer, and my computer does have the ability to read and write on disks. Just curious, and I still have the original code, so I'm open to modifications. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to burn a python program to a disc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187906/is-there-a-way-to-burn-a-python-program-to-a-disc)

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50879667/python-files-to-an-msi-windows-installer)

Comment: ...why wouldn't it be possible? If it's a standalone program, it should be fine. (Though of course it will only run on the CPU architecture and operating system for which it was built.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can.
It doesn't matter, what kind of storage you use to carry the python program on (or any other executable).

Just check if your code doesn't need to write any files somewhere in optical drive (it's read-only storage).

Or, even better, just copy your program from optical drive to an other computer HDD before running.

Comment: Thanks! That would explain why it wasn't working on my friends Mac that we were using to test the disk on. I made the exe on my Windows machine. Thanks for the information!